# How can I insert float values into integer type list in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

`bbox=[[100,53,64,64],[216,53,64,64],[88,69,64,64]]`

Here is my list and I want to insert new column as float data type. However, when I insert my float indices, all of my float values are int. How can I solve it ? For example, after insterting it, I want to have a list like `[[100,53,64,64,0.53],[216,53,64,64,0.66]..]` etc.

I am using this method for inserting :
`bbox=np.insert(bbox,4,conf_norm,axis=1)`
But it gives me a list like:

`[[100,53,64,64,0],[216,53,64,64,1],[88,69,64,64,0]]....`

So, how can I fix this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to be consistent.  Is this a `list` or `numpy` array?  Don't `numpy` functions on lists.

Comment: This is a list. I think problem is the np.insert method. How can I do that without uslng np.insert ?

Comment: `np.insert` returns an array, even if the input is a list.  You need to use ordinary list processing, iterating on the sublists, and adding the new values to each.

Answer (score 1):

Numpy arrays have a fixed datatype. You cannot mix ints and floats. (You can in Python lists.)

Comment: In python lists, how can I do it without using np.insert method?